# Visualise on a map the location of the photos inside a folder

Tags: macos, finder, maps, exif

Is there a software that I can point to a folder to see a map of the area of all the pictures present in that folder? With tiny thumbnails or dots.
Similar to what can be done directly on the iPhone, but for OS X.

Comment: all area maps at once?

Comment: iPhoto does just that

Comment: @Tetsujin yes it does, bot only one pic at time!

Comment: Are you on an old version of iPhoto? See http://i.stack.imgur.com/g5jw4.png which is a [not quite] random bunch of pictures selected from my Library

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is a $2 Mac app called Photo Geolocation from the Mac App Store:
[Photo Geolocation](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photo-geolocation/id954925820?mt=12)